# Error: Modernizr is not defined - adding class to header on mobile screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery

may someone help me please with this error message? My theme is using Modernizr in its theme.js file and I'd like to use it to add a class on the header on mobile screen by using my seperate custom.js file. My code itself seems to be okay, since it is working when I copy Modernizr from the theme.js file into my custom.js file. However, when I do not copy the jquery plugin into my custom.js file, I got a Modernizr is not defined error.

I already checked the other topcis on stackoverflow and inspeceted the html structure of my site. My custom.js file is directly loaded after the main.js file is loaded, therefore there might be no loading order issue. So is there a way getting this thing to work properly without including whole Modernizr twice? Since I am new to jQuery, maybe my comprehension about how things are working sometimes still underlies a basic mistake.

JS Script:

```
/* Mobile Header */
jQuery.fn.header-adding-mobile-styles = function() {
    if ( js_local_vars.disable_mobile_image_hovers != 1 ) {
        if ( Modernizr.mq( 'only screen and (max-width:' + js_local_vars.side_header_break_point + 'px)' ) ) {
            jQuery( '.header' ).addClass( 'is-mobile-header' );
        } else {
            jQuery( '.header' ).removeClass( 'is-mobile-header' );
        }
    }
};

// Header Mobile Styles on resize
jQuery( '.header').header-adding-mobile-styles();
jQuery(window).on( 'resize', function () {
    jQuery( '.header').header-adding-mobile-styles();
});
```

Comment: how do you included modernizr.js or modernizr.min.js?

Comment: Hey YOU, Modernizr is included in the theme.min.js file, which is being loaded, so it must be a minified version. Is this important?

Comment: Mh, you are right. When I load the scripts unminified it is working...

Comment: If you are directing a comment at someone on SO, prefix it with a `@`, that way the person you are referencing will get a notification. Without that @YOU might never revisit this question and see your comment. As the creator of the question you will always get notifications about comments on it. Likewise if you answer a question you will get notifications when someone comments on your answer; the person who asked the question you answered will also get them when someone comments on your answer.

Comment: @UselessCode, sorry, I did not know that up to now. Thanks for the correction! :-)

Comment: @YOU, I already wrote an answer, but was not clear about the fact, that I have to mark you with a @. You can look at my answer. I already found two ways to accomplish what I was looking for without the use of modernizr. Anyway it would be great to know how to solve the opening question. I also can write my own solution here, but do not know if this okay, since it would not be really topic related anymore.

Comment: You're very welcome :) More info on the comment system and what you can do with it can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Another useful thing you might not know about is that you can use a [limited sub-set of *Markdown*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in your comments.